# Working with possible null value in the where clause of a PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null, conditional-statements

I have an SQL query that goes like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT userID FROM User WHERE areaCode=? AND contactNo=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $areaCode ? $areaCode : null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $contactNo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

When $areaCode is `null`, this query would fail because `areaCode=null` needs to be tested with `areaCode IS NULL` instead. Is it still possible to parameterized such query?

Comment: Using COALESCE or IFNULL could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that  (i.e. parametrize) via [<=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT userID FROM User WHERE areaCode <=> ? AND contactNo=?");
```

Comment: If downvote, please, comment. `<=>` is a safe null-comparison operator